# How to retrieve List content in JSP from Hibernate Query Language

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hql

I Developed the program that retrieve the content from Database and store it in the List

```
 List<Student> studentList=session.createQuery("from Student s where s.lastName=:lastName and s.firstName=:firstName")
                                          .setParameter("lastName",lname)
                                            .setParameter("firstName",fname).list();
         for(Student studentinfo:studentList)
         {
             System.out.println(studentinfo);
         }
         model.addAttribute("result",studentList);
```

And i have passed the result to the JSP File

```
    ${result}
<c:forEach var="item" items="${result}">
    ${item}
</c:forEach>
```

I am getting the result like this

**"Student{id=6, firstName='arul', lastName='suju', address='s;lda'}"**

But i want print the value one by one,Can any one suggest better code in JSP

Comment: Well, instead of just ${item}, display (for example) ${item.lastName}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution by modifying the jsp code like this

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${result}">
    ${item.id}
    ${item.firstName}
    ${item.lastName}
    ${item.address}
</c:forEach>
```